# Etag is not present in web api response header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, etag

In Web API response, I'm trying to set Etag Header inside action of web api. but it's not present in response header.

**I can not set ETag using ActionFilter Attribute. I have to set it in action.**

```
        [CacheControl(MaxAge = 5)]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetStreamByPath(int presId)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            // Some Code here
            //testStream is obj.

            if (testStream != null)
            {
                var getEatg = ETagHelper.GetETag(testStream.LastModifiedDate.ToString());

                if (Request.Headers.Contains("If-None-Match") && Request.Headers.GetValues("If-None-Match").ToString() == getEatg)
                {
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
                }

                response.Headers.ETag = new EntityTagHeaderValue(String.Format("\"{0}\"", getEatg));

                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StreamContent(testStream.Stream) };
                response.Content.Headers.Add("content-type", " image/jpeg");
            }
            else
            {
                response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your header like below:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("ETag", String.Format("\"{0}\"", getEatg));
```